# Are rich-rules in firewalld applied before or after regular zone rules with a default "DROP" policy?

Tags: firewalld

As far as I know, there are 2 main ways to add rules in `firewalld`, **normal "zone" rules** and **rich-rules**. Also, I understand that when we set `target="DROP`, all new incoming connections will be dropped unless we add rules to allow selected incoming traffic.

I want to ask is there any standard pattern in which the `firewalld` rules will be applied to an incoming packet when we add new rules using regular zone rules vs rich-rules?

> For example, is this the order in which `firewalld` rules will always
> be applied:
>
> 1. Normal rules
> 2. Rich rules
> 3. Default drop policy rule

Comment: When in doubt you can use the lower level iptables / nftables commands to display the effective rule sets that firewalld generates and see how they're ordered and structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules in `firewalld` have priorities, and rules are applied so that the one with the lower priority gets evaluated first. If two contradictory rules have the same priority, the outcome is undefined.

The priorities are:

- Rich rules have a priority of 0, unless explicitly specified, in which case, they have the specified priority. Priorities can be between -32768 and 32767.
- Services have a priority of 0.
- Default zone rules (i.e. specified by `--set-target`) are processed last.

So if you have a `target=DROP` specified for a zone, any contradictory rule negates this. So adding a service or a rich rule will allow the service or rule in question. If you have a service, and a contradictory rich rule with a priority less than zero, the rich rule will have precedence. If a contradictory rich rule has a priority greater that zero, it is a no-op.